# Understanding how imports are working in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to understand how including works in `C++`. I have two questions about it. The first one is on how properly import the `.h` file. For example I created the following `HashNode.h` file:

```
namespace HashNode{
    template<class Data>
    class HashNode{
    private:
        Data data;
        HashNode *next;

    public:
        explicit HashNode(const Data &data);

        Data getKey();

        ~Node();
    };
}
```

So in the `HashNode.cpp` file, it should like:

```
#include "HashNode.h"

using namespace HashNode;

template <class Data> // ~~~ HERE 1 ~~~
HashNode::HashNode(const Data &data) {//todo};

template <class Data> // ~~~ HERE 2 ~~~
Data* HashNode::getKey() {
    //todo
}

HashNode::~Node() {
    //todo
}
```

This way it works but do I have to include `template <class Data>` beside each function which uses `Data`? Why it does not recognize `Data` without including `template <class Data>`?

Also I have created the `Hash.h` file which should use the `HashNode.h` file:

```
#include "HashNode.h"
using namespace HashNode;

namespace Hash {
    template <class Data>
    class Hash {
        typedef enum {
            GOOD = 0,
            BAD = -1,
            BAD_ALLOC = -2
        } Status;

    private:
        HashNode **hash;
        int capacity;
        int size;

    public:
        explicit Hash(int size);

        Status insertData(const Data &data);

        ~Hash();
    };
}
```

But I get the the following error: `Can't resolve type 'HashNode'`. Why it can't see the import?
In the `Hash.cpp` file I get `Unused import statement` for `#include "HashNode.h"`. Why is that?
Also, what if I want to include private functions - should them be in the `.h` file or in the `.cpp` file?

Comment: Why `namespace HashNode` around your `class HashNode`? That doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to name a `namespace` and a `class` in that `namespace` with the same identifier. Together with `using namespace`, this becomes very confusing - for me and as it appears for the compiler as well.

Comment: You should implement your templates in your headers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Importing is fundamentally different from including.

Comment: `template <class Data> // ~~~ HERE 1 ~~~
HashNode::HashNode(const Data &data) {//todo};` is actually defining a new template function in namespace HashNode and is not defining the HashNode method. For that you want `template <class Data>
HashNode<Data>::HashNode(const Data &data) {//todo};`

Comment: `#include "HashNode.h"` literally just means 'include the contents of the file "HashNode.h" here'.

Comment: "Unused import statement" is not a message that a C++ compiler would produce. I suspect that it comes from your IDE. Don't rely on your IDE's "live" error messages.

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything called "import". `#include` manipulates text files. It is completely oblivious to classes, namespaces, templates, or pretty much anything else you might find in a C++ source file.

Answer (score 0):

The member functions of a template class are themselves also templates. Because of this, they need to be defined with any required template parameters and template type definitions.

About your second question, it has to do with namespaces. As I see it, having namespace and class under the same naming might cause you ambiguity. Although, everything seems to be fine on the structural side of the code. Try using `#pragma once` or some kind of guards to prevent this kind of issues.